# Google Domain and Site title change - Strange results! HELP!

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search, title

The name of the Previous website was "Game&Util Foundation"
Now, I changed the name to "Mobi:HQ - The Social Sharing Platform"

I set up both 301 redirection AND used to change of address tool in webmasters.

But still, Google is displaying https://mobihq.org as "Game&Util Foundation".
Don't they ever read the  tags?

The first time it got indexed, everything was fine.
After 2 days, the title "Game&Util Foundation" was Added to EVERY SINGLE SEARCH RESULTS on google.
And all my google index looks like this :
[New page title] - Game&Util Foundation

Google has added the word "Game&Util Foundation" To every single index......

This is seriously disturbing.
Please help.

[image]

I tried fetching URLs manually. I did everything but google still ads "Game&Util Foundation" Tag to every single search result.

Please don't question me about the contents. I was hired by that board to look at technical stuff. Nothing I can do about it.

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked and answered many times already in various forms. The duplicate link is one of many suitable answers on the site on reasons why the title may be different. If you believe its reading the old title then it can take Google 1-3 weeks for the update to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which CMS you are using but it may happen due to title given to website from backend! It may happen that Google datacenter fetching your website may still have older version and may take time to get it resolved.

I checked crawled pages of your website and found that only home page has this issue right? keep sharing the status.